# C++ Header Autocompletion in Doom Emacs

Tags: doom, c++

I have the following init file:

```
:tools
       ;;ansible
       ;;debugger          ; FIXME stepping through code, to help you add bugs
       ;;direnv
       ;;docker
       ;;editorconfig      ; let someone else argue about tabs vs spaces
       ;;ein               ; tame Jupyter notebooks with emacs
       (eval +overlay)     ; run code, run (also, repls)
       ;;gist              ; interacting with github gists
       lookup              ; navigate your code and its documentation
       lsp
       magit             ; a git porcelain for Emacs
       ;;make              ; run make tasks from Emacs
       ;;pass              ; password manager for nerds
       ;;pdf               ; pdf enhancements
       ;;prodigy           ; FIXME managing external services & code builders
       ;;rgb               ; creating color strings
       ;;taskrunner        ; taskrunner for all your projects
       ;;terraform         ; infrastructure as code
       ;;tmux              ; an API for interacting with tmux
       ;;upload            ; map local to remote projects via ssh/ftp

       :os
       (:if IS-MAC macos)  ; improve compatibility with macOS
       ;;tty               ; improve the terminal Emacs experience

       :lang
       ;;agda              ; types of types of types of types...
       (cc +lsp)                ; C/C++/Obj-C madness
       ;;clojure           ; java with a lisp
       ;;common-lisp       ; if you've seen one lisp, you've seen them all
```

Now I cannot seem to get autocompletion to work, though lsp is enabled.

My screen looks like this:

[image]

I cannot seem to find any step by step docs for configuring doom emacs for c++. How can I go about setting up doom emacs for c++ development on Mac OS 10.15.6?

Comment: Did you have a backend installed? I guess the default would be clangd.

Comment: For header auto completion, there is an interesting package called [company-c-headers](https://github.com/randomphrase/company-c-headers), you can check it out and see if it works for you.
Good luck!

Comment: Hello, yes I have followed the instructions here:

https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/tree/develop/modules/lang/cc

It still doesn't seem to work for autocompletion of headers. Any ideas?

Comment: For c++ completion, you have to include the path location to company-c-headers:
`(add-to-list 'company-c-headers-path-system "/usr/include/c++/8/")`
The last part, is the route where the c++ libraries are located.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mac, with `clangd`. It was fixed by adding a `compile_flags.txt` file to the project root, with `CPPFLAGS` options copied from the Makefile.

Make sure to split CPPFLAGS with an option per line in the file.

```
-g
-Wall
```

etc.

https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clangd/Installation.html